# Angular 2 Component global lifecycle hooks

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to add global lifecycle hooks for every component instead of doing it one by one ?
Example: I want on each component initialization to be called a function.

Comment: No, not that i'm aware of since lifecycle events are per instance.

Comment: Take a look at answer provided in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420241/angular-2-global-lifecycle-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's not *officially* possible.

I haven't seen an example like this in the Angular 2 docs. The component lifecycle events are implemented per instance.

PS: If you find a hackish way to do it, I wouldn't recommend you to do so. I bet there's a better alternative to handle your use-case :)