# Angular 2: "Global" lifecycle hooks?

Tags: angular

**TL;DR**

We are building an app with Angular 2 and would like to register a "global" `ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy` function. With "global" I mean that the function is executed for every component, without needing to be explicitly implemented for every component. Is this possible?

**Detailed**

Some (but not all) of our components need to register something in a global service once they are loaded (e.g. `ngOnInit`) and unregister it again, once they are unloaded (e.g. `ngOnDestroy`). Here are two approaches I can think of:

- Implement this logic in every component which needs to do so (in `ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy`).
- Implement this logic in a base class which calls abstract methods implemented by the sub classes which specify, what needs to be registered/unregistered.

Both approaches aren't really satisfying:

- In the first I need to implement the whole logic over and over again. Yeah, I know, I could put the "boiler plate"-code in a helper class or something. But it seems to be slightly implicit, "hidden" in the regular Angular lifecycle. Having a speaking name (e.g. interface/base class) seems more explicit.
- In the second all classes need to extend the same, common base class. But what if they should also extend some other base class (multiple inheritance)?

That's why i came up with following idea:

Why not replace the above mentioned abstract class with an interface that can be implemented by all the required components. I would then register a global function which is executed on every `ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy` of all the components (if possible - e.g. in an module, routing, etc.?). In the function I would check if the component implements the interface and if it does, then call the appropriate function to get the type specific stuff to be registered.

**My questions**

- Can Angular 2 do this? I.e. can a "global lifecycle hook" (or something like that) be registered?
- Or is this a totally wrong approach anyway?
- Any other/better ideas?

Answer (score 10):

Forcing the behaviour for the entire app wouldn't be a good idea, this affects third-party components as well for starters.

Boilerplate code can be moved into concrete base class. There are solutions for JS/TS multiple inheritance, e.g. [@mixin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-decorators), see also [TypeScript guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html).

Since base class methods are fixed, class mixin can be expressed as a simplified decorator:

```
class CustomLifecycle implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {
  constructor(
    public originalNgOnInit: Function,
    public originalNgOnDestroy: Function
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    ...
    if (typeof this.originalNgOnInit === 'function') {
      this.originalNgOnInit();
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    ...
    if (typeof this.originalNgOnDestroy === 'function') {
      this.originalNgOnDestroy ();
    }
  }
}

function Lifecycled() {
  return function (target: Function) {
    const customLifecycle = new CustomLifecycle(
      target.prototype.ngOnInit,
      target.prototype.ngOnDestroy
    );

    target.prototype.ngOnInit = customLifecycle.ngOnInit;
    target.prototype.ngOnDestroy = customLifecycle.ngOnDestroy;
  }
}
```

And it can be used like

```
@Component({ ... })
@Lifecycled()
class SomeComponent { .... }
```

The implementation is limited to `ngOnInit`, etc. prototype methods, arrow members require a constructor to be patched.

Comment: Can we override all lifecycle hooks of angular using this ?

Comment: Yes, we can override any prototype method.